# Package attachment fails in the Terminal but not in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I opened R in my Mac OS X Terminal application by typing `R`.

I then printed the session info by typing `sessionInfo()` and got the following:

Session info

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.1
```

Package attachment:

```
> library(Rsamtools, lib.loc = 'output/software/r/package/installation')
Loading required package: GenomeInfoDb
Loading required package: BiocGenerics
Loading required package: parallel

Attaching package: ‘BiocGenerics’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:parallel’:

    clusterApply, clusterApplyLB, clusterCall, clusterEvalQ,
    clusterExport, clusterMap, parApply, parCapply, parLapply,
    parLapplyLB, parRapply, parSapply, parSapplyLB

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    IQR, mad, sd, var, xtabs

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    anyDuplicated, append, as.data.frame, cbind, colMeans, colnames,
    colSums, do.call, duplicated, eval, evalq, Filter, Find, get, grep,
    grepl, intersect, is.unsorted, lapply, lengths, Map, mapply, match,
    mget, order, paste, pmax, pmax.int, pmin, pmin.int, Position, rank,
    rbind, Reduce, rowMeans, rownames, rowSums, sapply, setdiff, sort,
    table, tapply, union, unique, unsplit, which, which.max, which.min

Loading required package: S4Vectors
Loading required package: stats4

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
 2: library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)
 3: loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
 4: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 5: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 6: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 7: tryCatch({    attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc    ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)    env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps)}, error = function(e) {    P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e)))         paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])    else ""    msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s",         sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))    if (logical.return)         message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)    else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)})
 8: library(pkg, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, lib.loc = lib.loc,     quietly = quietly)
 9: .getRequiredPackages2(pkgInfo, quietly = quietly)
10: library(pkg, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, lib.loc = lib.loc,     quietly = quietly)
11: .getRequiredPackages2(pkgInfo, quietly = quietly)
12: library(Rsamtools, lib.loc = "output/software/r/package/installation")

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
```

As you can see, this creates a segmentation fault. However, if I do the same in Rstudio, it works fine:

Session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3 tools_3.4.3    yaml_2.1.18
```

Package attachment:

```
> library(Rsamtools, lib.loc = 'output/software/r/package/installation')
Loading required package: GenomeInfoDb
Loading required package: BiocGenerics
Loading required package: parallel

Attaching package: ‘BiocGenerics’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:parallel’:

    clusterApply, clusterApplyLB, clusterCall, clusterEvalQ,
    clusterExport, clusterMap, parApply, parCapply, parLapply,
    parLapplyLB, parRapply, parSapply, parSapplyLB

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    IQR, mad, sd, var, xtabs

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    anyDuplicated, append, as.data.frame, cbind, colMeans, colnames,
    colSums, do.call, duplicated, eval, evalq, Filter, Find, get, grep,
    grepl, intersect, is.unsorted, lapply, lengths, Map, mapply, match,
    mget, order, paste, pmax, pmax.int, pmin, pmin.int, Position, rank,
    rbind, Reduce, rowMeans, rownames, rowSums, sapply, setdiff, sort,
    table, tapply, union, unique, unsplit, which, which.max, which.min

Loading required package: S4Vectors
Loading required package: stats4

Attaching package: ‘S4Vectors’

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

    expand.grid

Loading required package: IRanges
Loading required package: GenomicRanges
Loading required package: Biostrings
Loading required package: XVector

Attaching package: ‘Biostrings’

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

    strsplit
```

I tried to make the Terminal session and the Rstudio sessions the same by detaching yaml from Rstudio but I failed. `detach('package:Rsamtools', unload = TRUE)` works but not `detach('package:yaml', unload = TRUE)`. I doubt that not having tools and yaml is the reason for failure in the Terminal though.

This is obviously really annoying because I want to run my R script with `Rscript` in a snakemake pipeline. Can anybody help me resolve this problem, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was in an Anaconda environment called `python3env` in the terminal that contains Python 3 as the default Python version. After deactivating the environment and rerunning the R code again, it worked. It's a mystery to me why this should be the case. I know that my different conda environments have different packages installed in them but I thought that if the R package is saved to the hard disk, it could be loaded into an R session no matter in which conda environment I am. But oh well, it's working now.